# How can i get time of my recorded audio in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudiorecorder

I am recording audio using `AVAudioRecorder`,and now i want to get exact time duration of my recorded audio,how can i get that.

i have tried this:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:avAudioRecorder.url options:nil];
CMTime time = asset.duration;
double durationInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(time);
```

But my `time` variable return NULL and `durationInSeconds` return 'nan',what does that means by nan.

**UPDATE**

`user1903074` answer have solved my problem but just for curiosity ,is thair any way to do it without `AVAudioplayer`.

Comment: nan means not a number. is asset NULL as well?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using `AVAudioPlayer` with `AVAudioRecorder` than you can get the `audioPlayer.duration` and get the time.

like this.

```
 NSError *playerError;

 audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:yoururl error:&playerError];

 NSlog(@"%@",audioPlayer.duration);
```

But only if you are using `AVAudioPlayer` with `AVAudioRecorder`.

**UPDATE**

Or you can do like this.

```
//put this where you start recording
     myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

// a method for update
- (void)updateTime {
    if([recorder isRecording])
    {

        float minutes = floor(recorder.currentTime/60);
        float seconds = recorder.currentTime - (minutes * 60);

        NSString *time = [[NSString alloc] 
                                    initWithFormat:@"%0.0f.%0.0f",
                                    minutes, seconds];
    }
}
```

steel you can get some delay becouse their is some microsecond value,and i dont know how to clip it .but thats all.

Comment: Yes, i am using AVAudioPlayer with AVAudioRecorder.

Comment: @lipid : But i think the recorded sound's duration will not always be same as the sound played using AVAudioPlayer. (Correct me if i am wrong!)

Comment: Yes, i am agree with ishwar,the small change is their but if i find any good method than this then i let you know.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is simply to keep track of the start date, and at the end, calculate the time passed.
It worked for me because the user is starting and stopping the recorder.

In the recorder class

```
NSDate* startTime;
NSTimeInterval duration;

-(void) startRecording
{
   //start the recorder
   ...
   duration = 0;
   startTime = [NSDate date];

}

-(void) stopRecording
{
   //stop the recorder
   ...
   duration = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startRecording];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of the answers here use the same really poor time formatting that gives results like "0.1" for 1 second elapsed or "0.60" for 1 minute. If you want something that gives you a normal looking time like 0:01 or 1:00 then use this:

```
let minutes = Int(audioRecorder.currentTime / 60)
let seconds = Int(audioRecorder.currentTime) - (minutes * 60)
let timeInfo = String(format: "%d:%@%d", minutes, seconds < 10 ? "0" : "", seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the original question was looking for an answer in Objective-C, but for those looking to do so in Swift, this works with Swift 4.0:

```
let recorder = // Your instance of an AVAudioRecorder
let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: recorder.url)
let duration = player?.duration ?? 0.0
```

Assuming you have a valid recorder, then you will get a duration value, which is given as a `TimeInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

Update @Dilip's excellent answer to Swift 5.3:

```
//put this where you start recording
myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


// a method for update
 @objc func updateTime(){
     if recorder.isRecording{
         let minutes = floor(recorder.currentTime/60)
         let seconds = recorder.currentTime - (minutes * 60)
         let timeInfo = String(format: "%0.0f.%0.0f", minutes, seconds)
     }
 }
```

this should be used with

```
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)
        audioSession.requestRecordPermission({ (isGranted: Bool) in
            
        })
    } catch  {}
```

Answer (score 0):

before you stop the recording, try get .currentTime

```
let duration = audioRecorder.currentTime
audioRecorder.stop()
```